# How to Convert to json object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create json in this format:

```
[
{
"name":"aaa_aaaurf",
"region":"F&R",
"checkins":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,3],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,3],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]
}
]
```

I have the following code:

```
var checkins = {};
checkins["1"] = "200";
checkins["2"] = "100";
checkins["3"] = "200";
checkins["4"] = "300";
checkins["5"] = "100";
checkins["6"] = "50";
checkins["7"] = "80";
checkins["8"] = "60";
checkins["9"] = "50";
checkins["10"] = "40";
checkins["11"] = "30";
checkins["12"] = "200";

var display2 = {};
display2["name"] = "aaa_ct";
display2["region"] = "F&R";
display2["checkins"] = checkins;

console.log( JSON.stringify(display2) );
```

However i am getting the data in the following format:

```
{"name":"aaa_ct",
 "region":"F&R",
 "checkins":{"1":"200","2":"100","3":"200","4":"300","5":"100","6":"50","7":"80","8":"60","9":"50","10":"40","11":"30","12":"200"}}
```

I would like to enclose the checkins details in the braces as shown above. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
var checkins = {};
checkins["1"] = "200";
checkins["2"] = "100";
checkins["3"] = "200";
checkins["4"] = "300";
checkins["5"] = "100";
checkins["6"] = "50";
checkins["7"] = "80";
checkins["8"] = "60";
checkins["9"] = "50";
checkins["10"] = "40";
checkins["11"] = "30";
checkins["12"] = "200";
var checkins2 = [];
for(var i in checkins) checkins2.push([i, checkins[i]]);
var display2 = {};
display2["name"] = "aaa_ct";
display2["region"] = "F&R";
display2["checkins"] = checkins2;
console.log( JSON.stringify(display2) );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SdLWR/

Answer (score 0):

You've made checkins into an object, make in an array instead and push the values in either like this:

```
var checkins = [];
checkins.push(200);
checkins.push(100);
```

or like this:

```
var checkins = [200,100];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating object instead of array, so do that way:

```
var checkins = [ 200, 100, 200, 300, 100, 50, 80, 60, 50, 40, 30, 200 ];
```

And please, use highly available documentation on Java-Script language and its data types like: object, array, etc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array